# How to check if list element has string or tuple in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to check if list element has string or tuple. If element is str then create tuple.

I tried below code

```
def func(cols:Sequence[str]):
    return [(col, None, None) for col in cols if isinstance(col, str) else col]
    
func(["col1"])
func([("col1",str,None)])
```

Comment: What is `existence_cols`? You intended this as a parameter?

Comment: What is `col1`? Did you intend "col1"? Are you really planning to place `int` in your tuple?

Comment: you cannot call `func([("col1",int,int)])`  this is invalid

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, there is nothing invalid in that line.

Comment: if the op wants just generic `int` instead of an example of execution why does then he/she pass "col1" instead of `str`? this mixture confuses me

Comment: Confusing yes, but invalid: no (at least not *that* statement).

Comment: @Panda, replacing `int` with `str` and `None` doesn't reduce the confusion.

Comment: It could be to pass types for a checking function, does it really matter? @Panda you can give some context about what the code will be doing. That might avoid trying to solve a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors in your code, I imagine you want:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

def func(existence_cols: Sequence[str]):
    return [(col, None, None) if isinstance(col, str) else col
            for col in existence_cols ]
    
func(["col1"])
# [('col1', None, None)]

func([("col1",int,int)])
# [('col1', int, int)]
```

Errors:

- missing import
- missing parameter in function
- incorrect position of the conditional in list comprehension
- missing quotes in `func([(col1,int,int)])`

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues with the code you provided. Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
def func(existence_cols):
    result = []
    for col in existence_cols:
        if isinstance(col, str):
            result.append((col, None, None))
        elif isinstance(col, tuple):
            result.append(col)
    return result

result1 = func(["col1"])
result2 = func([("col1", int, int)])

print(result1)  # Output: [('col1', None, None)]
print(result2)  # Output: [('col1', int, int)]
```

Comment: Why did you remove the list comprehension?